# No Activity found to handle Intent` { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=sms:

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am trying to invoke the Android default SMS Application's Delete Messages Activity from within my application when the user selects a menu item . My Android Version is 4.2.2.

I am getting the following error in logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException<br/>
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {    act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=sms:
```

Here is the code:

```
public class SmsWiperActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_wiper);

    TextView wItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = i.getStringExtra("item");
    // displaying selected product name
    wItem.setText(product);
}




public void invokeMessagingApplication(MenuItem item)
{

    /*Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(smsIntent);*/

    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    startActivity(smsIntent);


    /*Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING);
    startActivity(smsIntent);*/



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sms_wiper, menu);

    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_settings:
           //settings();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_MessagingApplication:
        invokeMessagingApplication(item);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

The Logcat file is

```
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(MenuInflater.java:235)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:144)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter.onItemClick(ListMenuPresenter.java:178)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1507)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3292)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4545)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)     08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.view.MenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.onMenuItemClick(MenuInflater.java:231)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    ... 16 more
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE dat=sms: }
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3434)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3395)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3630)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3598)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    at com.rishi.android.contactswiper.SmsWiperActivity.invokeMessagingApplication(SmsWiperActivity.java:42)
08-16 13:30:39.277: E/AndroidRuntime(29487):    ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The error log seems clear enough. There is no Activity on your device that can handle such Intent.
Are you sure this API is public?

BTW, you should always check if an Activity can handle an Intent to avoid crash like this one:

```
    public static boolean isIntentAvailable(Context context, Intent intent) {
        return !context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).isEmpty();
    }
```

Comment: How can I check if the API is public ? I want to launch the default delete SMS Activity of the SMS Application which allows the user to select n delete the SMS on the device. One can get to that activity by starting the Messaging app and then pressing key on the bottom left corner of the phone and choosing the Delete option

Comment: If this function is not documented on the Android documentation, it means it is not a public API.